# Recursive method returning undefined method '[]'

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure why this recursive method is returning `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

```
def test_method(a, b)
    (a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : 1) + test_method(a[1..-1], b[1..-1])
end
```

edit: I am sending in strings for the arguments to compare them.

Comment: What arguments are you sending to this method to get that exception?

Comment: I'm sending in strings to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, at one time, it will reduce to empty string and then to nil. And then causes NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass.

Something like this is happening:

```
'ss'[1..-1] => 's'
'ss'[1..-1][1..-1] => ""
'ss'[1..-1][1..-1][1..-1] => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not checking whether a and b are empty arrays or not. At one time that will reduce to empty array

before calling you should write

```
 if not (a.empty? or b.empty?)
  (a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : 1) + test_method(a[1..-1], b[1..-1])
 end
```

Comment: I planned on adding empty string checking later on. Do I need to check it right off the bat? All the tests I have been doing have been with strings longer than 5 characters in length, so I assumed this wouldn't be a problem yet.

Comment: but at one time like a[6..-6] will gives back nil. Check this out in console

Comment: If it's recursive, at some point you you have to reach the end.

Comment: but you have to stop some where explicitly. It will not happen automatically.

Comment: Ah, i get it. Can't believe I didn't see it before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're iterating over an ever smaller array/string/whatever, you have to account for reaching the end of it. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, but this'll at least stop it from blowing up:

```
def test_method(a, b)
  return 0 if a.nil? || b.nil?
  (a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : 1) + test_method(a[1..-1], b[1..-1])
end
```